# Как отключить ассеты родителя в виджете наследнике?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть виджет, наследующийся от `yii\bootstrap4\Modal`. Этот дефолтный виджет подключает у себя скрипты, такие как `bootstrap.js` и `bootstrap.css` определённой версии. А я бы хотел использовать другие версии, но с таким же функционалом, что написан в виджете.

Как можно заменить эти стили конкретно в виджете? Как можно их отменить и не применять стили и скриты родителя?

**upd**

методы обнуления типа

```
'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => false,
            'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapPluginAsset' => false,
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => false,
            'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

не работают.проблема в том, что родитеь в себе использует трейт, в котором есть метод, который регистрирует ассет. И поэтому видимо конфиг не отрабатывает. Хотя и на других ассетах пробовал. Не знаю почему, но такое обнуление просто не работает

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/structure-assets#customizing-asset-bundles

Comment: @Dmitriy пробовал - не работает.

Comment: @Dmitriy проблема в том, что родитеь в себе использует трейт, в котором есть метод, который регистрирует ассет.... и поэтому видимо конфиг не отрабатывает. Хотя и на других ассетах пробовал. Не знаю почему, но такое обнуление просто не работает

Comment: Создать свои кастомные ассеты и указать там то, что надо?

Comment: @fedornabilkin увы, но подобное приводило к тому, что как бы я не втыкал ассеты - он всегда подгружался до ассета виджета и поэтому перетирался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у родительского виджета был есть трейт, в котором есть метод, в котором подключается ассет

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function registerPlugin($name) {
    $view = $this->getView();

    BootstrapPluginAsset::register($view);

    $id = $this->options['id'];

    if ($this->clientOptions !== false) {
        $options = empty($this->clientOptions) ? '' : Json::htmlEncode($this->clientOptions);
        $js = "jQuery('#$id').$name($options);";
        $view->registerJs($js);
    }

    $this->registerClientEvents();
}
```

Пока ничего лучшего в голову не пришло, кроме как переопределить данный метод, вписав те же самые строки, за исключением подключения ассета.

Увы, хоть какие-либо другие способы не помогают